# Installation of Docker on window 10 pro failed: requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise/Home (18363+)

Tags: docker, windows-10

[image]

I am trying to install docker on windows machine but fail. I have checked for all prerequisite, and my machine fulfills all. The issue is:

```
Docker Desktop 4.1.1.
Installation Failed:One prerequisite is not fullfilled.
Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise/Home (18363+).

Configuration details
Window:-10 pro
Build Number:-10240.
```

I want to know , is there any way to install docker on this build version (10240).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know , is there any way to install docker on this build version (10240).

You can not. This is declared clearly in the error message you see and in [official document](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#system-requirements):

> - WSL 2 backend
>
> Windows 10 64-bit: Home or Pro 2004 (build 19041) or higher, or
> Enterprise or Education 1909 (build 18363) or higher.
>
> - Hyper-V backend and Windows containers
>
> Windows 10 64-bit: Pro 2004 (build 19041) or higher, or Enterprise or
> Education 1909 (build 18363) or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Windows Version in the Registry:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type in *"regedit"*
3. In the Registry Editor, go to `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`
4. Right-click on *EditionID* and click *Modify*
5. Change Value Data to Professional
6. Press OK

Edit Windows CurrentBuild (set 18363[or the currentbuilt docker asked]) and CurrentBuildNumber (set 18363[or the currentbuilt docker asked]) the same way.